# How to import an array of arrays from CSV in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv, numpy

so basically I'm new to Python and there's something I'm not being able to do. I'm importing data from a CSV and I need my data_2d to look like this:

```
data_2d = [ [30, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0],
        [32, 10, 0,10, 3, 5, 0],
        [5, 9, 0, 25, 10, 8, 3],
        [22, 10, 0  ,17, 5, 6, 0],
        [7, 15, 0, 30, 3, 5, 0]]
```

Instead, with my current code, I get this:

```
[['30' '15' '0' '15' '0' '0' '0']
['32' '10' '0' '10' '3' '5' '0']
['5' '9' '0' '25' '10' '8' '3']
['22' '10' '0' '17' '5' '6' '0']
['7' '15' '0' '30' '3' '5' '0']]
```

My code is here:

```
data_2d = [ [30, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0],
        [32, 10, 0,10, 3, 5, 0],
        [5, 9, 0, 25, 10, 8, 3],
        [22, 10, 0  ,17, 5, 6, 0],
        [7, 15, 0, 30, 3, 5, 0]]

data_2d = []

with open('file.csv', newline='\n') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        data_2d.append(row)

data_array = np.array(data_2d)
data_array = np.delete(data_array, (0), axis=0)
data_array = np.delete(data_array, (0), axis=1)

print("data_array")
print(data_array)
```

The CSV file currently looks like this:

```
Time_Activity;SITTING;STANDING;LAYING;WALKING;WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS;WALKING_UPSTAIRS;RUNNING
8;30;15;0;15;0;0;0
9;32;10;0;10;3;5;0
10;5;9;0;25;10;8;3
11;22;10;0;17;5;6;0
12;7;15;0;30;3;5;0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an immediate fix, use the [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method to convert your array of strings to `int`:

```
data_array = data_array.astype(int)
```

In addition, `np.delete` is inefficient and not recommended; use slicing instead where possible. Here are a couple of ways you can avoid Python-level loops altogether:-

#### `numpy`

Using NumPy, you can utilize [`np.genfromtxt`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
arr = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=1)[:, 1:]
```

#### `pandas`

Alternatively, via Pandas you can use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
arr = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';').iloc[:, 1:].values

print(arr)

# array([[30, 15,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0],
#        [32, 10,  0, 10,  3,  5,  0],
#        [ 5,  9,  0, 25, 10,  8,  3],
#        [22, 10,  0, 17,  5,  6,  0],
#        [ 7, 15,  0, 30,  3,  5,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

The csv file is read as a string. You can convert the row from string to int while appending. This can be done using `map` function.

**Code:**

```
data_2d.append(list(map(int,row)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. 2 things can help achieve your goal and simplify the code a bit.

1. Skip the header so you don't worry about deleting it later.
2. Cast the strings to int before you append.

Example code that works on your input:

```
  data_2d = []
  with open('file.csv', newline='\n') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader) # this will skip that header
    for row in reader:
      data_2d.append([int(x) for x in row]) #this just means take each string and make it an int before appending.
```

Result:

```
[[8, 30, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0], 
[9, 32, 10, 0, 10, 3, 5, 0], 
[10, 5, 9, 0, 25, 10, 8, 3], 
[11, 22, 10, 0, 17, 5, 6, 0], 
[12, 7, 15, 0, 30, 3, 5, 0]]
```

Some helpful links that explain both additions:
https://evanhahn.com/python-skip-header-csv-reader/
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python