# How to extract API data from multiple urls stored in a csv file (a), then save each individual dataset/table to its own csv file (b,c,d etc)

Tags: python, api

i'm trying to get data from an API, I literally have 0 experience coding but have somehow managed to write a script that will extract the data from an inputted url then save it to a csv file. The problem is that i have hundreds of datasets to fetch and by inputting the urls and 'save as' file names manually will take forever. I have a csv file containing all the dataset urls and the corresponding filenames to save the extracted data as.

So for example, the data urls are akin to this:
https://api.football-data-api.com/league-matches?key=07275****3d8002&season_id=6135

the corresponding filename will be:
England Premier League_2021

This is what I've come up with so far but like I say, to input everything manually will take forever and a day...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://api.football-data-api.com/league-matches?key=07275****3d8002&season_id=6135"

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }



response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
myjson = response.json()
myjson_data = myjson['data']

data_csv = pd.DataFrame(myjson_data)
data_csv.to_csv('England Premier League_2021.csv')
```

Is there a way of automating the data retrieval? Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too broad. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a loop of some kind.
It is slightly unclear how the file CSV file you have, is structured.  As stated in the comments, your file has the headers (columns) 1. "data_url" and 2. "filename" :

```
|data_url|filename|
|https://api.football-data-api.com/league-matches?key=07275****3d8002&season_id=6135|England Premier League_2021.csv|
|Some_other_url|Some_other_file_name.csv|
```

You are on the right track.
The steps taken to do what you want to do now, is, you need to first read this CSV you have into an array of some kind ([How to import an array of arrays from CSV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537391/how-to-import-an-array-of-arrays-from-csv-in-python)).  If you want to make this step simple at first, only keep the url's and name the output files the same as then you only need to work with one column for starts (i.e. only a single array with the list of url's you are going to use) https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/conver-pandas-column-to-list/.

In the second part of the code, you need to loop over each item (url / filename / line in the CSV) in your array (like a for-loop below) and perform the action you want inside the loop, an example (from a similar task I've done) using f-strings in Python below.  The part between the curly braces is where you'll put the part of the url or payload that changes with each iteration of the loop.

```
import requests

url = "https://hpcsaonline.custhelp.com/cc/ReportController/getDataFromRnow"

headers = {
    put_headers_here
}

result=[]
list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

for x in list:
    payload =  "regNumber=&firstName=&surName=" + f'{x}*'+ "put_other_part_of_payload_here"


    r = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    for p in data["data"]:
        print(p)
        result.append(p)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv("HPCSA_results_2022.csv")
```

For your script it will look more like the following (assuming your payload and headers stay the same between requests):

## Using list() Function

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("datapath.csv")
list =  list(df["data_url"])

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

for x in list:
    url = x
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
    myjson = response.json()
    myjson_data = myjson['data']

    data_csv = pd.DataFrame(myjson_data)
    write_filename = x + ".csv"
    data_csv.to_csv(write_filename)
```

#UPDATE: Using the iloc command (likely better / easier with your csv which contains columns 1. "data_url" and 2. "filename" - note these are in position 0 and 1 respectively in the dataframe ):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("datapath.csv")
list =  list(df["data_url"])

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

for i in range(0,len(list)):
    url = df.iloc[i][0]
    filename = df.iloc[i][1]

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
    myjson = response.json()
    myjson_data = myjson['data']

    data_csv = pd.DataFrame(myjson_data)
    write_filename = filename + ".csv"
    data_csv.to_csv(write_filename)
```

Comment: The csv file containing the url list, named: datapath.csv, contains two columns. The first, headed: data_url - this contains a list of all the urls from which i want to extract the data. The second column headed: filename, is a list containing names i want to assign to each csv file which will be exported.

Comment: Then I would load that whole csv into a pandas dataframe first and with 2 for-loop functions and the iloc[y][x] command, read it line for line to produce your output.      
`url = list_of_urls.iloc[y][0]`   AND `filename = list_of_urls.iloc[y][1]`

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for your file structure.  Let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have that first problem figured out now but have run into a new problem lol, I have posted a new question if you care to assist, thanks